# The elegant way to read Customer ID from URI in TMS Sparkle?

Tags: delphi, tms

i'm developing a rest API with TMS Sparkle and i would like to know the elegant way to read the customer **{ID}** from this request :

http://localhost/v1/customers/**{ID}**

I could just do reverse read in the final characters until i find a "/" character, but doesn't seen's the 
 elegant way to me, there's another way to do it ?

This **{ID}** value is a part of the RequestedPath, but im wondering if there's a property which hold this value ?

I already read the documentation of the [Examining the Request](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/business/sparkle/doc/web/examining_the_request.html) doc tutorial, but there's no mention of how read complementary values from the request.

Comment: Check the Sparkle.Utils unit. If I remember correctly, there are some utils to help you with this

Comment: Thank you for your response John, but i'm using trial, how can i check the Classes/methods of a unit without the source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inspect the `Request` you can access the different parts of it via the `URI.Segments` property like this:

```
procedure TMySparkleModule.ProcessRequest(const C: THttpServerContext);
var
  r: THttpServerRequest;
  str: string;
begin
  r:=C.Request;
  for str in r.Uri.Segments do
    ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you John, that is exactly what a was looking for. The Segments property is a string array containing all the segments of the url, for example : /v1/customer/70 would be Segments[0] = v1, Segments[1] = customer, Segments[2] = 70